# seleccionar un elemento por su atributo en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, div, atributos

¿como obtengo el valor del div por su atributo s?

```
<div s="hola">es un ejemplo</div>
```

es posible sin usar jquery. con Solo javascript puro

Comment: e buscado un todo el dia y no encuentro una forma.

Comment: por eso hago la pregunta no encuentro nada sobre el tema

Answer (score 5):

Puedes utilizar los selectores de javascript, especificamente el `document.querySelector()`. Con esto puedes obtener el elemento HTML

```
let container = document.querySelector('div[s=hola]');
```

O si prefieres solo el contenido, puedes obtener solo el texto y todos los componentes internos como un string

```
let texto = document.querySelector('div[s=hola]').innerText;
let innerHTML = document.querySelector('div[s=hola]').innerHTML;
```

Esto deberia poder ayudar a tu pregunta. Para mas detalles puedes revisar la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) o ver algunos [ejemplos](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-queryselector/) que te pueden ayudar a entender mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los elementos `div` que cumplan con tu condición puedes usar el siguiente selector de JS:

```
let elemento = document.querySelector('div[s="hola"]')
```

Ten en cuenta que este selector sólo devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla con ese atributo, si quieres aplicarlo para todos deberías usar `querySelectorAll`.

Entonces para obtener el contenido de `elemento` simplemente usas:

```
let texto = elemento.innerText // devuelve únicamente el texto
let html = elemento.innerHTML // devuelve el HTML interno
```